# break lines automatically

Tags: tables

how to break automatically the lines in the following table? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{table}[H]
    %\begin{center}
    \topcaption{Comparaison des aspects généraux des méthodes d'analyse et de modélisation des connaissances.}
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]
    {
        \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
        \hline
        \diaghead{\theadfont Diag ColumnmnHead II}%
        {Auteurs}{Attributs}&\thead{Caractéristiques}&\thead{Objectif}&\thead{Destinaires}&\thead{Type}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Etendue}}&\thead{Propriétés}\\
        \hline
        \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{Ing pédagogique} & \footnotesize{Ing logicielle}& \footnotesize{}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        \footnotesize{HNa XXXXXXXXXXXX} & \footnotesize{Basé sur l'analyse du comportement d’apprenants et l'analyse des traces d’usage (Usage Tracking Language)} & \footnotesize{Réingénierie d’un scénario pédagogique, Constitution d'une mémoire des indicateurs partagés} & \footnotesize{Enseignants} & \footnotesize{Patrons} & \footnotesize{x} & \footnotesize{-} & \footnotesize{}\\
        \hline
        \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
        \hline
        \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    %\end{center}
    \label{tab: aspectsGeneraux}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `c` columns are single line, use `p{3cm}` or whatever width you need, then lines are broken to that width

Comment: I would suggest using `tabulary`: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73882/need-help-to-adjust-horizontal-spaces-in-a-table/73890#73890